# Signed apk getting Key has invalid in Nexus phone

Tags: android

I am trying to log in with Facebook in android .It is working on all phones but when i am trying to the same with the signed apk in Nexus phone then i am getting the error for "Key hash invalid...".

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin>keytool.exe -exportcert -alias Symphony -k
eystore C:\Users\theonetech25.THEONETECH\Desktop\Symphony\Symphony.KeyStore | C:
\openssl\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl base64
Enter keystore password:  ******
StuoveV3OHOmDSOAnied5dNBvQM=
```

I have tried to generate key by two ways:
1) Programmatically
2) Using OpenSSL

But getting same error with both key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having problem with your `SHA-1 key`...

Try to add the HashKey which is shown in the error dialog and add it in your developer account.. And run program again..

Hope this information helps you..

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have use haskey which was shown in facebook dialog in developer account and problem got solved.